# php header redirection doesn't work in if else statement

Tags: php, wordpress

```
if($_POST){

    if($checkout_form == "checkout"){
        if($orderpersonname == "" || $orderpersonemail == ""){
            $checkouterror = "<p><font style=\"color: red;\">Please enter your full name and email address before checking out</font></p>";
        }elseif(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $orderpersonemail)){
            $checkouterror = "<p><font style=\"color: red;\">Please enter a valid email address</font></p>";
        }elseif(!isset($_POST['tnc'])){
            $checkouterror = "<p><font style=\"color: red;\">Please accept the terms and conditions to complete this entry before checking out</font></p>";
        }
        else{
            header("Location: http://www.google.com.my");
            exit;


        }
    }
}
```

I have the code above if there's no error occur it will redirect me to a checkout page, in this case I use google page as a sample. But what it does is actually brings me back to the same URL and there's a blank space above my website header and all the sidebar and content become blank. Why is that so? How to solve this redirection issue?

Comment: turn display_errors on or look in your error logs, your page is erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) for this issue. I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: wont solve it if there is a whitespace before his very first script tag

Answer (score 0):

One main issue I have ran into with these is the headers were already sent.
Try using `ob_start()`.

As said above, this will not do anything if you have whitespace...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your braces in right positions.

```
if ($_POST){
    if ($checkout_form == "checkout") {
        if($orderpersonname == "" || $orderpersonemail == "") {
            $checkouterror = "<p><font style=\"color: red;\">Please enter your full name and email address before checking out</font></p>";
        }elseif(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $orderpersonemail)) {
            $checkouterror = "<p><font style=\"color: red;\">Please enter a valid email address</font></p>";
        }elseif(!isset($_POST['tnc'])) {
            $checkouterror = "<p><font style=\"color: red;\">Please accept the terms and conditions to complete this entry before checking out</font></p>";
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.google.com.my");
        exit;
    }
}
```